# react-native android: string.matchAll - undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

not sure what's going on here.

I have code that works fine in iOS:

```
    const bolds = /\*\*([^\*]+)\*\*/g;
    const italics = /[^\*]\*([^\*]+)\*/g;
    const images = /\[\[\[(.*)\]\]\]/g;
    const footnotes = /xx(\d*)/g;
    const hyperlinks = /[^\[](https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;

    const matchRegexes = {
        hyperlinks: [...text.matchAll(hyperlinks)],
        bolds: [...text.matchAll(bolds)],
        italics: [...text.matchAll(italics)],
        images: [...text.matchAll(images)],
        footnotes: [...text.matchAll(footnotes)],
    };
```

I'm using it to identify a custom markup / certain text patterns.

When I attempt to load the View that uses this code I get this error pointed at the first `text.matchAll`

`undefined is not a function`

What is going on here? It looks like matchAll is relatively new to the spec, but it's working for ios, why would it not be included with android?

Comment: what is console log text?

Comment: Are you asking for a solution, or an explanation? (Probably only Android internal devs can answer *why*)

Comment: @CertainPerformance ideally both. The workaround is obviously to implement this without matchAll, but I don't understand why I can't. This more of a problem for react-native devs than android devs though as it looks like the underlying javascript engine is the issue.

Comment: @WilliamWang what console log text? I'm not logging anything. And these expressions are unloggable because they throw an error before having any value.

Comment: have you ever found a solution ? same issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64935512

Comment: @ssc this happens because of an older version of javascript is being run on the android that doesn't include `matchAll`. Older versions of node have the same problem. Im not sure if its possible to update the js backend on android, but I'm using this in the meantime: https://www.npmjs.com/package/string.prototype.matchall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also you can use an external library:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/string.prototype.matchall

```
import matchAll from 'string.prototype.matchall';
const array = [... matchAll(str, regexp)];
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like matchAll is not supported by the RN's JS engine on Android, but it will likely be available in RN 0.64 [[0](https://github.com/facebook/hermes/issues/381)].

Until then, you can gather all matches yourself manually using `RegExp.exec()` [[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll#regexp.exec_and_matchall)]:

```
const str = 'the dog doggedly jumped over the moon';
const regex = new RegExp('dog[a-z]*', 'g');
let match;
let matches = [];
while ((match = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  matches.push(match[0]);
}

console.log(matches); // [ "dog", "doggedly" ]
```

This works on both iOS and Android.