# React Native: <string>.matchAll is not a function

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I get a weird error when running my React Native app:

Some sample code:

```
const { url } = <incoming object>;
const reURL   = <my regex>;

console.debug('url:', url);
console.debug('typeof url:', typeof url);

matches = [...url.matchAll(reURL)];
```

Log output:

```
url: <as expected>
typeof url: string
```

Error message:

```
TypeError: url.matchAll is not a function. (In 'url.matchAll(reURL)', 'url.matchAll' is undefined)
```

Everything works fine on iOS, the error only occurs on Android.

Pretty up to date environment, updated all `npm` packages a couple of days ago.

Does anyone have the slightest idea where to even begin searching for a solution ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx to extract all matches from string using RegExp.exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323417/regex-to-extract-all-matches-from-string-using-regexp-exec)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. `String.matchAll` does not work for Android. You should use `match` instead `matchAll`.

Example:

```
const regex = new RegExp(text, 'ig');
const arr = string.match(regex);
```

You will get an array match regex

Comment: string.match does not function the same way as matchAll at all. A `match` on multiple values simply returns an array of those values. `matchAll` returns an iterator whose values objects with the position of each match in the string and can also handle multiple capture groups which `match` also cannot. So yeah, `match` is not a replacement for `matchAll` which is much more useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string.prototype.matchall` to polyfill.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/string.prototype.matchall

```js
import matchAll from 'string.prototype.matchAll'

matchAll.shim()
```

Answer (score 0):

For us, this issue was solved by conditionally evaluating matchAll:

```
ourSring.matchAll?.(expr);
```

Our working theory is that the first time this method is accessed, some native async regex initialization is run, but takes some time to bind the method, resulting in undefined `matchAll` method.
Subsequent evaluations work properly for us.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the call to `str.matchAll(regex)` with the recursive function in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53422000/6355024) did the job perfectly for me.

Pasting here the function with TS support for completeness:

```
/**
 * Recursive function which replaces the usage of `str.matchAll(regex)` which happens to be troublesome on Android once compiled.
 * @param regex - regex expression to be executed. If passed with the `/g` global flag the result will return all matches.
 * @param str - string value to be searched for matches by the regex expression
 * @param matches - parameter used to pass on the current resulting array through recursion iterations
 * @returns array of all matches found while executing the regex
 */
export function findAllMatches(regex: RegExp, str: string, matches: RegExpExecArray[] = []) {
  const res = regex.exec(str)
  res && matches.push(res) && findAllMatches(regex, str, matches)
  return matches
}
```

Ensuring nobody in the codebase would try to use `matchAll` again could be achieved by adding the following `es-lint` rule:

```
"no-restricted-syntax": ["error", {
   "selector": "CallExpression[callee.property.name='matchAll']",
   "message": "You should use the findAllMatches function instead."
}]
```